# How to add column label once one column reaches the value of another in pandas and calculate number of days it took to reach that value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of different IDs where one column is a fixed value and the other is variable, changing by date. I want to look at each ID and create a new column that labels whether or not it has reached the fixed value and another column that calculates the time it took to reach the value.

| ID | Date | Fixed Value | Varible Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01 | 500 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-02 | 500 | 200 |
| 1 | 2021-03 | 500 | 300 |
| 1 | 2021-04 | 500 | 400 |
| 1 | 2021-05 | 500 | 500 |
| 2 | 2021-01 | 400 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-02 | 400 | 20 |
| 2 | 2021-03 | 400 | 70 |
| 2 | 2021-04 | 400 | 400 |
| 2 | 2021-05 | 400 | 500 |
| 3 | 2021-01 | 300 | 10 |
| 3 | 2021-02 | 300 | 300 |
| 3 | 2021-03 | 300 | 500 |
| 3 | 2021-04 | 300 | 600 |
| 3 | 2021-05 | 300 | 700 |

What I want is something like this:

| ID | Date | Fixed Value | Varible Value | Reached_Fixed_Value | Time_To_Reach |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01 | 500 | 10 | No | na |
| 1 | 2021-02 | 500 | 200 | No | na |
| 1 | 2021-03 | 500 | 300 | No | na |
| 1 | 2021-04 | 500 | 400 | No | na |
| 1 | 2021-05 | 500 | 500 | Yes | 5 months |
| 2 | 2021-01 | 400 | 5 | No | na |
| 2 | 2021-02 | 400 | 20 | No | na |
| 2 | 2021-03 | 400 | 70 | No | na |
| 2 | 2021-04 | 400 | 400 | Yes | 4 months |
| 2 | 2021-05 | 400 | 500 | Yes | 4 months |
| 3 | 2021-01 | 300 | 10 | No | na |
| 3 | 2021-02 | 300 | 300 | Yes | 2 months |
| 3 | 2021-03 | 300 | 500 | Yes | 2 months |
| 3 | 2021-04 | 300 | 600 | Yes | 2 months |
| 3 | 2021-05 | 300 | 700 | Yes | 2 months |

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you probably need groupby and cumsum ... you should try some stuff and come back once you have some effort put into this (maybe you have already, in which case you should post your attempt and why it is wrong)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can do it this way:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m')

df["Reached_Fixed_Value"] = np.where(
    (df["Varible Value"] >= df["Fixed Value"]), "Yes", "No"
)
df["Time_To_Reach"] = (
    df.query('Reached_Fixed_Value == "Yes"')
      .groupby("ID")["Date"]
      .transform("min")
      .dt.strftime("%m")
      .str.strip("0") + " months"
)
df
```

Output:

```
    ID       Date  Fixed Value  Varible Value Reached_Fixed_Value Time_To_Reach
0    1 2021-01-01          500             10                  No           NaN
1    1 2021-02-01          500            200                  No           NaN
2    1 2021-03-01          500            300                  No           NaN
3    1 2021-04-01          500            400                  No           NaN
4    1 2021-05-01          500            500                 Yes      5 months
5    2 2021-01-01          400              5                  No           NaN
6    2 2021-02-01          400             20                  No           NaN
7    2 2021-03-01          400             70                  No           NaN
8    2 2021-04-01          400            400                 Yes      4 months
9    2 2021-05-01          400            500                 Yes      4 months
10   3 2021-01-01          300             10                  No           NaN
11   3 2021-02-01          300            300                 Yes      2 months
12   3 2021-03-01          300            500                 Yes      2 months
13   3 2021-04-01          300            600                 Yes      2 months
14   3 2021-05-01          300            700                 Yes      2 months
```

With time calculation:

```
df["Time_To_Reach"] = (
    ((df.query('Reached_Fixed_Value == "Yes"')['Date'] - df.groupby("ID")["Date"]
      .transform("min")) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M')).round().add(1).cummin()
      )
df
```

Output:

```
    ID       Date  Fixed Value  Varible Value Reached_Fixed_Value  Time_To_Reach
0    1 2021-01-01          500             10                  No            NaN
1    1 2021-02-01          500            200                  No            NaN
2    1 2021-03-01          500            300                  No            NaN
3    1 2021-04-01          500            400                  No            NaN
4    1 2021-05-01          500            500                 Yes            5.0
5    2 2021-01-01          400              5                  No            NaN
6    2 2021-02-01          400             20                  No            NaN
7    2 2021-03-01          400             70                  No            NaN
8    2 2021-04-01          400            400                 Yes            4.0
9    2 2021-05-01          400            500                 Yes            4.0
10   3 2021-01-01          300             10                  No            NaN
11   3 2021-02-01          300            300                 Yes            2.0
12   3 2021-03-01          300            500                 Yes            2.0
13   3 2021-04-01          300            600                 Yes            2.0
14   3 2021-05-01          300            700                 Yes            2.0
```

Comment: Yep, do the string conversion. Otherwise, well need to do some fancy month calculation and add 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need two things:

1. Masking for duplicated IDs to get the last row for the value assignment.
2. Grouping to get the number of months for each ID

Create the masking using `pd.DataFrame.duplicate` to keep only the last row for each IDs, then assign a new column as `Time_To_Reach` with `NaN` values, then group the dataframe by `ID`, and get the required value i.e. size of the group adding `month` string, finally assign the values to `Time_To_Reach` column based on the masking created.

```py
mask = ~df.duplicated('ID', keep='last')
df['Time_To_Reach'] = float('nan')
df.loc[m, 'Time_To_Reach'] = (df.groupby('ID')['Date']
                                .apply(lambda x: str(len(x)) + ' months')
                                .values
                              )

    ID     Date  Fixed Value  Varible Value Time_To_Reach
0    1  2021-01          500             10           NaN
1    1  2021-02          500            200           NaN
2    1  2021-03          500            300           NaN
3    1  2021-04          500            400           NaN
4    1  2021-05          500            500      5 months
5    2  2021-01          400              5           NaN
6    2  2021-02          400             20           NaN
7    2  2021-03          400             70           NaN
8    2  2021-04          400            400           NaN
9    2  2021-05          400            500      5 months
10   3  2021-01          300             10           NaN
11   3  2021-02          300            300           NaN
12   3  2021-03          300            500           NaN
13   3  2021-04          300            600           NaN
14   3  2021-05          300            700      5 months
```

Comment: This assumes contiguous monthly entries for `Date` which may or may not be a safe assumption. However, It also doesn't address the "time to reach" aspect where the month counting is supposed to stop when `Varible Value` reaches `Fixed Variable` Group 2 reaches 400 at 4 months for example.